# Python- Tkinter Radio Button changes not being registered

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am trying to use tkinter to create a basic program. It is not capturing my radio button input.
It should display a screen with a title and a next button. If the next button is pressed it should bring up another window with two radio buttons and a next button. If that one is pressed it should bring up a third screen telling you what you choose. Currently, it tells you that you chose nothing no matter what

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

def forward():
    root2=Tk()
    mainframe2=ttk.Frame(root2)
    mainframe2.grid(row=0,column=0)
    pick=StringVar()
    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe2, text='A', variable=pick, value='A').grid(row=1,column=1)
    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe2, text='B', variable=pick, value='B').grid(row=2,column=1)

    #What I have tried
    #ttk.Button(mainframe2, text='Next',command=lambda: advance(pick)).grid(row=3,column=1)
    ttk.Button(mainframe2, text='Next',command=partial(advance,pick)).grid(row=3,column=1)
    #ttk.Button(mainframe2, text='Next',command=advance).grid(row=3,column=1)#if you this and def 
advance(args) it says pick is undefined

    root2.mainloop()
def advance(pick):
    choice=pick.get()
    screen3=Tk()
    mainframe3=ttk.Frame(screen3)
    mainframe3.grid(row=0,column=0)
    result=str('You Chose '+choice)
    ttk.Label(mainframe3, text=result).grid(row=1,column=1)
    screen3.mainloop()

root = Tk()
mainframe=ttk.Frame(root) #create a screen
mainframe.grid(row=0,column=0)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Welcome to my Broken Program').grid(row=1,column=1)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Next',command=forward).grid(row=2,column=1) 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tk won't work the way you expect if you create more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: It worked thank You!